# How do I map POCO model classes to existing DB tables using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have existing POCO model classes and an existing DB. The OO model classes and relational DB tables don't map directly to each other.

How do I use Entity Framework to map these? All of the tutorials I have seen are either Code First (which goes and generates new DB tables), Model first (which generates new DB tables and POCOs) and DB First (which generates new POCOs).

I want none of these! I want to map between existing POCOs and DB tables. What's the best way of doing this? Can I use the visual designer, or do I have to do it in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create mappings which map your entities to database structure (I suggest to use fluent mappings). Then just disable database generation:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);
```

and provide connection string to existing database:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(string connectionStringName)
      : base(connectionStringName)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use the Fluent API, does that mean you don't use the EDMX visual designer at all?

Comment: Also, how do you map one POCO class to two DB tables? I have found the Table attribute that you put on the top of the class, but don't see how you can map two tables to that.

Comment: To answer my own questions I added in the comments... 1) Fluent API and Annotations are part of Code First. 2) When you use Code First, there is no data model / edmx / xml configuration. 3) Having one POCO using two tables is called Entity Splitting.

Comment: @Anthony sorry, was afk. Yes, with code first you don't need edmx files - data model representation is built from classes and mappings. You can't map one class to two tables - there should be two classes.

Comment: so this is an example of "Code First with Fluent API"? Having such a hard time figuring out to write POCOs mapped to an existing table without all thi  s EDMX stuff. Any good tutorial / docs on the topic?

Comment: where do you actually map the POCO properties to the table columns?